Flutter web - photo picker integration with google photo
I want my Flutter Web application Image Picker to be able to select photos from "Google Photo".
like a doe's in this application example:

When image picker is open it shows an option to select image from google photo via google picker API.
Is there a way to do it on Flutter Web?
